# Valgrind reports uninitialized value inside standard library (vfprintf.c)

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have a function which does a `vsnsprintf` into a temporary buffer in an object created on the stack.

In the object's constructor I initialise the first character of the buffer to null.

Valgrind complains about an **uninitialised value** created on the stack in `vfprintf.c`

**Full working example below, followed by valgrind output**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

struct tmp_buf
{
    tmp_buf() { *b = 0; }
    mutable char b[1024];
};

char const* va_stack_str(const char* format, va_list ap, const tmp_buf& b = tmp_buf())
{
    vsnprintf(b.b, sizeof(b.b), format, ap);
    return b.b;
}

char const* stack_str(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    const char* str = va_stack_str(format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s", stack_str("hello %s", "world"));
    return 0;
}
```

The app works as expected, but running it through valgrind complains about **uninitialised values**

My valgrind command line is `valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --quiet`

**Valgrind output:**

```
==30513== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==30513==    at 0x4E828F3: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1661)
==30513==    by 0x4E8B388: printf (printf.c:33)
==30513==    by 0x400A73: main (main.cpp:28)
==30513==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==30513==    at 0x4E80BF6: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:235)
==30513== 
==30513== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==30513==    at 0x4F233B0: __write_nocancel (syscall-template.S:81)
==30513==    by 0x4EB0A82: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1261)
==30513==    by 0x4EB1F5B: _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:538)
==30513==    by 0x4EB3ADD: _IO_flush_all_lockp (genops.c:848)
==30513==    by 0x4EB3C39: _IO_cleanup (genops.c:1013)
==30513==    by 0x4E730FA: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:95)
==30513==    by 0x4E73194: exit (exit.c:104)
==30513==    by 0x4E58ECB: (below main) (libc-start.c:321)
==30513==  Address 0x4025000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==30513==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==30513==    at 0x4E80BF6: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:235)
```

Changing the `tmp_buf` constructor to `memset` the whole buffer doesn't change valgrind's output

```
tmp_buf() { memset(b, 0, sizeof(b)); }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is C++? Looks more like C.

Comment: @TNA - yes, `tmp_buf` has a constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I am not super familiar with Valgrind, I can see a clear problem in your code, and can offer my best guess as to why Valgrind is complaining in the manner it is.

First, the problem:

The function `va_stack_str` is returning a pointer to the member `b` of argument `b` which is of type `const tmp_buf&`. Because this function has no control of the lifetime of the object referenced by this argument, it is returning a pointer whose validity can only be guaranteed until the end of the full expression in which it is called. In the case that argument `b` is initialized by a temporary (which is exactly how it is used by `stack_str`), then the end of the full expression is exactly the duration that the returned pointer is valid.

The function `stack_str` goes on to store the pointer returned by `va_stack_str` in the local variable `str` and then return it. By this time, the full expression in which `va_stack_str` was called has ended, so the pointer is dangling- it is pointing to a buffer that was allocated on the stack but has since been deallocated.

The code works likely because that portion of the stack that the buffer did exist on is not overwritten by the time it is read and so still contains the contents of what used to be the buffer.

Why I think valgrind issues 'uninitialized value' warnings:

`vfprintf` certainly allocates some stack space for local variables, some of which are probably allocated in the same stack memory that used to be the buffer that we have asked it to print. When `vfprintf` then uses this buffer (the one that we passed it), Valgrind sees this memory not as our original buffer (which has been deallocated), but as the address of the local variables that `vfprintf` allocated.

My guess is that one of these local variables is uninitialized at the point which `vfprintf` scans through the buffer that we passed it looking for a terminating NULL character. In this circumstance, it examines memory pointing to its own uninitialized local variable which normally would not happen because `vfprintf` would initialize it later, but before it intends to use it. `vfprintf` expects that you will pass a pointer to a buffer that you have allocated and not one that will end up pointing to it's own local variables!